# How to get all headers in array

Tags: go, fasthttp

I tried to get all headers in handler and faced some difficulties.

valyala/fasthttp has the needed methods and I can get headlines one by one, but I don`t see the obvious way to get all of the headers.

So, How can I get all of the headers into an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `request.Header.VisitAll`. See [related doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestHeader.VisitAll).

```
r.Header.VisitAll(func (key, value []byte) {
    log.Printf("%v: %v", key, value)
})
```

Comment: If you are going to answer a question, it would be great if you took a moment to edit it. Also, if the question was worth answering, isn't it likely worth an upvote? Thanks and Cheers!